# Trigger Event on route change Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hey I have two header components `header.component` and `header-home.component` so when your on the homepage you see the `header-home` and when your not you just see `header` now In my header component Ive set up an `.active` class that puts an underline underneath the selected `nav` item which works when going between the `nav` on the pages with the `header.component` but not when I click on the `nav` in the `header-home` which takes me to a page that now has `header`

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Event, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';
import { NgIf } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  routeHidden = true;

  title = 'app';

  constructor(private router: Router)
  {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe( (e) => {
      if (e instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (e.url === '/') {
          this.routeHidden = false;
        } else {
          this.routeHidden = true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header *ngIf="routeHidden"></app-header>
<app-header-home *ngIf="!routeHidden"></app-header-home>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgStyle } from '@angular/common';
declare var jquery: any;
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  title: any;
  image: any;

  constructor(
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    $('.hamburger').click(function(){
      $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
      $('.mobile-nav_ul').toggleClass('mobile-nav_ul_active');
    });

    $('.mobile-nav_ul').click(function(){
      $('.hamburger').toggleClass('is-active');
      $('.mobile-nav_ul').toggleClass('mobile-nav_ul_active');
    });

    $('ul li').on('click', function() {
      $('li').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
    });
  }
```

basically is there a way I can grab that click event in the `header-home.component` and then apply the `.active` class to the `nav` item I clicked on in the `header.component`

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: My eyes! jQuery code on the Angular Component's `ngOnInit`... Sorry, but why you don't want this piece of logic to be implemented angular-natively?

Comment: Do you know a solution to the problem that can be run natively? basically Im refactoring a website so Im putting in all the old jquery code for now so it functions and then I will convert to angular

Comment: Regarding jQuery... Update your template elements with `(click)` event bindings to set up `HeaderComponent` fields, say, `isActiveHamburger` and `isActiveMobile` flags. Then use `[ngClass]` to set approprite css classes to your elements according to that flags.